# Python GUI does not Close Child Process

Tags: python, linux, pygtk

My work asked me to port our program (that someone else wrote) from Windows to Linux.  I have been able to successfully run the Python script and the executable program that the Python script calls in Linux.

The Python script creates a GUI, and the script uses the following command to close the GUI when the user is done:

```
window.connect("destroy", self.close_application)
```

This is in the `def __init__(self):` portion of the script.  The GUI is created it calls the executable as a process as follows:

```
MY_EXE = 'My_Program'
EXE_ARGS = "-d -l"
sh = MY_EXE + ' ' + EXE_ARGS

self.proc = custom_popen.Popen('sh', std=custon_popen.PIPE, stdout=custom_popen.PIPE)
```

The problem that I am having is that the Python script never attempts to close My_Program when the user clicks the close button on the GUI.  The script does properly close the GUI.

So, my question is how do I link the users selection to close the GUI to a command to close the My_Program process in the Python script?

Any help is appreciated.  Also, if it is of note, the script requires pygtk 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Does the external program read from stdin and then exit? If it does, does your `close_application` method call `self.proc.stdout.close()`?

If the external program doesn't exit automatically (e.g.: when it's done reading input or doing a simple task), then you may need to kill it explicitly with [`Popen.close()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) (Python 2.6+) or [`os.kill()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Marc. My externel program is an emulator of an avionics unit, so it basically is intended to run until it is told to close. I have looked at the Popen.close() and os.kill() functions, I guess what I am trying to communicate is that I don't know enough about the Python format to know how I transition to the Popen.close() command when it catches the users action of closing the GUI.

Comment: Maybe a better way of stating it is that the externel executable is intended to run until the user closes the GUI.  The GUI itself has a box that the user can click on and select a file to feed into the executable as input.  However, when the executable does not have any new data inputs, it just sends an "I'm alive" status to the guy he is communicating to on the other end of his socket.  So, I just need to link the action of the user clicking the "x" in the corner of the gui to a place that I can call Popen.close().

Comment: Okay.  I found where the script calls the closing steps, so now I need to know how to properly close the application.  How do I get the proper pid for the child executable?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to succesfully kill the app with the os.kill() function.  So, I consider this solved for me.